# ctypes pass an array of byte

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I want to call this C function from a DLL in python2.7

```
uint8_t DLL_CONV Mag(uint8_t *t1, uint8_t *t2, uint8_t *t3);
```

This function write data to the arrays sent by reference.

This is my python code so far

```
_mag = hDLL.Mag
#_mag.argtypes =[ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)]
_mag.argtypes =[ctypes.c_ubyte *100,ctypes.c_ubyte *100,ctypes.c_ubyte*100]
_mag.restype = ctypes.c_ubyte
def mag():
    t1 = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 100)()
    t2 = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 100)()
    t3 = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 100)()
    s = _mag( (ctypes.c_ubyte *100)(t1), (ctypes.c_ubyte *100)(t2), (ctypes.c_ubyte *100)(t3) )
    return t1,t2,t3
```

I always got a TypeError at `s = _mag()`

Comment: I think `s = _mag(t1, t2, t3)` should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I undefined `argtypes`
and just send the arrays like so

```
s = _mag( (t1), (t2), (t3) )
```